# Realizar una query que devuelva todas las filas de una fecha en concreto y todas las traducciones relacionadas en una misma fila

Tags: mysql, sql

Estoy teniendo problemas para poder obtener lo que quiero. Me explico:

Tengo las dos siguientes tablas con una relación 1:n

**Tabla blog:**

[image: Tabla blog]

---

**Tabla blog_tranlations**

[image: Tabla blog_translations]

---

**Tabla resultado**

[image: Resultado]

El código que uso es:

```
SELECT b.id, b.category, bt.title 
FROM blogs b 
INNER JOIN blog_translations bt ON b.id = bt.blog_id 
WHERE DATE(b.created_at) = '2010-11-12';
```

---

Pero este código da como resultado:

[image: Resultado erroneo]

Y esto es incorrecto.

¿Cuál es la query para conseguir la **Tabla resultado**?

Realizar una query que devuelva todas las filas de **blog** de una fecha en concreto y
todas las traducciones relacionadas en una misma fila

Gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Podrias poner la instruccion CREATE de tus tablas y el insert into si fueras muy amable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¿Algo así?:

Retorna una fila por cada blog, y todos los títulos de blog_tranlations de cada blog en una columna separados por comas.

```
SELECT b.id, b.category, GROUP_CONCAT(bt.title SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM blogs b 
INNER JOIN blog_translations bt ON b.id = bt.blog_id 
WHERE DATE(b.created_at) = '2010-11-12'
GROUP BY b.id, b.category;
```

No hace falta la subconsulta en la query de @"Edgar Vazquez":

```
SELECT b.id, b.Category, 
  max(case when bt.language = 'es' then bt.title end) title_es,
  max(case when bt.language = 'en' then bt.title end) title_en,
  max(case when bt.language = 'ca' then bt.title end) title_ca
FROM blogs b 
INNER JOIN blog_translations bt ON b.id = bt.blog_id 
WHERE DATE(b.created_at) = '2010-11-12'
GROUP BY b.id, b.category;
```

El único inconveniente es que si agregás un idioma tendrás que agregar una linea mas al SELECT, pero no se me ocurre una solución mejor.

Comment: Lo estaba haciendo. He leido la documentación.

Comment: Hola @nachospiu no, no es un concat. Es una columna por cada title

Comment: Ah, al ser variable el número de titles se te va a complicar.

Comment: No, solo son esos tres, los que están en la tabla blog_translations

Comment: ah, ok, pensé que cada blog podía tener n titles.

Answer (score 1):

De acuerdo a lo que dices podrías hacer uso de un case para evaluar por el lenguaje que debes de mostrar, aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como, no cree todos los campos de tu tabla para no tomarme mas tiempo,

```
CREATE TABLE blog
    (`id` int, `Category` varchar(30))
;

    
CREATE TABLE blog_tranlations
(`id` int, `blog_id` int,Language VARCHAR(3),Title VARCHAR(100));

INSERT INTO blog VALUES (1,'NEWS');
INSERT INTO blog_tranlations VALUES (1,1,'es','Noticias del mundo');
INSERT INTO blog_tranlations VALUES (2,1,'en','news of the word');
INSERT INTO blog_tranlations VALUES (3,1,'ca','Notices the mon');
```

-----------------SELECT

```
select bt.id, bt.category, bt.title,
  max(case when bt.language = 'es' then bt.title  else '' end) title_es,
  max(case when bt.language = 'en' then bt.title  else '' end) title_en,
  max(case when bt.language = 'ca' then bt.title  else '' end) title_ca
from
(
    SELECT b.id, b.category, bt.title,bt.language
    FROM blog b 
    INNER JOIN blog_tranlations bt ON b.id = bt.blog_id 

) bt
group by  bt.id, bt.category;
```

Omite el where ya que no lo agregue, pero básicamente seria esto con tus columnas el resultado lo puedes observar aquí.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/da38cc/2

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: Para filtrar por la fecha solo hay que poner el where debajo del INNER JOIN. Funcionó perfectamente, muchas gracias!

Comment: Perfecto... :D  Saludos

Answer (score 1):

Tomando como referencia la base de datos que construyó @EdgarVazquez te puedo proponer la siguiente *solución*

```
SELECT blog.id,
       blog.Category,
       (
           SELECT blog_tranlations.Title
           FROM blog_tranlations
           WHERE blog_tranlations.Language = 'es'
       ) AS Español,
       (
           SELECT blog_tranlations.Title
           FROM blog_tranlations
           WHERE blog_tranlations.Language = 'en'
       ) AS Inglés,
       (
           SELECT blog_tranlations.Title
           FROM blog_tranlations
           WHERE blog_tranlations.Language = 'ca'
       ) AS Otro
FROM blog;
```

- Mediante las [subconsultas](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) generamos las columnas nuevas
- En cada subconsulta filtramos el título eligiendo de la tabla `blog_tranlations` el mismo y con un `WHERE` indicamos el idioma requerido

  - Esta acción sería por cada uno de los casos
- Les damos un *nombre* a cada subquery, de otro modo el nombre de la columna sería la consulta misma